# How to merge elements of a collection in one array using Eloquent

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I'm trying the following:

I'm getting all clinic_tests related to my patients using the following function:

```
public function getPatientsClinicTests(Specialist $id)
  {
        $patientClinicTests = $id->patients()
            ->with('PatientClinicTests', 'PatientClinicTests.Patient.User')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('PatientClinicTests')
            ->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); });

        $result = [];
        foreach ($patientClinicTests as $array) {
            $result = array_merge($result, $array->toArray());
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

First group of code:

```
$patientClinicTests = $id->patients()
                ->with('PatientClinicTests', 'PatientClinicTests.Patient.User')
                ->get()
                ->pluck('PatientClinicTests')
                ->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); });
```

Brings me a collection of arrays as follows:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 16,
      "patient_id": 7,
      "medical_condition_id": null,
      "patient": {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 7,
        "pigment_id": 14,
        "id_medical_history": "6219116421",
        "user": {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Austen Wiegand",
        }
      }
    },
    .....
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 22,
      "patient_id": 1,
      "medical_condition_id": null,
      "patient": {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 1,
        "pigment_id": 14,
        "id_medical_history": "6219116421",
        "user": {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Gregor Wiegand",
        }
      }
    },
    .......
  ]
]
```

As I need to return one array of elements I combine the arrays I got as follows:

```
$result = [];
    foreach ($patientClinicTests as $array) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $array->toArray());
    }

    return $result;
```

This returns one array as follows:

```
[
    {
      "id": 16,
      "patient_id": 7,
      "medical_condition_id": null,
      "patient": {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 7,
        "pigment_id": 14,
        "id_medical_history": "6219116421",
        "user": {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Austen Wiegand",
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "patient_id": 1,
      "medical_condition_id": null,
      "patient": {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 1,
        "pigment_id": 14,
        "id_medical_history": "6219116421",
        "user": {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Gregor Wiegand",
        }
      }
    },
    .......
]
```

I would like to know if there is a smarter option to return as one array of elements using Eloquent instead a foreach statement.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yeah you can `flatten()` method from laravel collections

Answer (score 0):

you could use all() method to convert your collection to an array:

```
$patientClinicTests = $id->patients()
            ->with('PatientClinicTests', 'PatientClinicTests.Patient.User')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('PatientClinicTests')
            ->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); })->all();
```

please note that if you want to iterate over your array you should rebuild the array indexes after filtering ... you can do that using 'values' method:

```
$patientClinicTests = $id->patients()
            ->with('PatientClinicTests', 'PatientClinicTests.Patient.User')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('PatientClinicTests')
            ->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); })->values()->all();
```

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#introduction

Comment: thanks a lot for answer, but I cannot figure out how to avoid the foreach statement with that you said :( What Im looking for is to get one array, not an array of arrays as Im having before foreach

Comment: to solve this problem i recommend joining your table instead of load relations, then select PatientClinicTests.*

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a collect method over the array to allign it in a single array

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections

the link may be helpful

```
$collection = collect($patientClinicTests);
$collections = $collection->values()->all();
```

maybe this will work

Comment: thanks a lot for answering...using flatten()->all() I hgot what I wanted, but your post helped me to look and find the solution. Thanks a lot again my friend

Comment: @BerTsacianegudelTepuy i am glad i could be some help for you mate

Answer (score 0):

Flatten method helps me to give a single array without using foreach statement an array_merge() function:

```
$patientClinicTests = $id->patients()
            ->with('PatientClinicTests', 'PatientClinicTests.Patient.User')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('PatientClinicTests')
            ->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value); })->flatten()->all();
```

I will test using table joining as it has been recommended